# Can the Stack Exchange for Android app be found outside of Google Play?

Tags: support, android-app

The [Stack Exchange for Android](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/) app can be obtained [from the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).

For people with Android devices that don't have Google Play access, is there another way of getting the app?

For example, other app stores or a direct download of the .APK file.