# Can I get a direct download link for the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I am Persian, and as some of you know, Google Play denies service to Iran. It became a common practice here to download .apk files and install them later on.

Can Stack Exchange give a direct link to the Android application? This way we are getting our software right from the source. Yes, it is possible to use a third-party services such as Aptoide, but it spams its users.

Comment: @StevenV no sure it isnot, I do have google play app on the device and I know marvin app is reliant on the google play.

Comment: I'm not familar with the restrictions.  Do you have access to most of the Google Add-ons like those referenced in the "possible duplicate"?  If not, then the duplicate answers your question.  If you do, then this is a slightly different question and not a dup.

Comment: If Google Play is blocked, presumably some of the core services that the app relies on will also be blocked?

Comment: @Joe No I is not, I even had installed the marvine and used it via aptoid, but I had to flash the whole device due to extent of aptoid spam

Comment: Got to hate when sanctions come in the expense of information sharing :(

Comment: As the OP indicates that the sanctions do not interfere with the necessary Google Add-ons referenced [in this answer to the dup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217764/182513), this is not a duplicate and voting to reopen

Comment: If you want to be technical it's a [dupe of this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221161/can-the-stack-exchange-for-android-app-be-found-outside-of-google-play), however, that was closed as a dupe of the question this question was closed as a dupe of, but now since this question is reopened... I don't know.

Comment: I understand where stackexchange concerns are coming from, but the request  is just for a reliable `.apk` links version to version. Just what you packing for the google play. Paste them somewhere like google drive or dropbox. No support, no nothing else. Finding a marvin `.apk` files is not that hard. The issue here is the security. That we know this .apk file is provided by stackexchage.

Comment: @hichris123 you are probably right and if this gets an answer, might we worth reclosing that question as a dup of this one.  Unfortunate for that question though is this one was a bit better.

Comment: @m_hmt well, let's see what SE says as they are likely the only people who can provide a correct answer here.  At least the question is open now.